# Querying the first 48 hours of activity after a user appears in a table (HiveQL / SQL)

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm working with a Hive table that represents traffic on a website and contains columns such as `user_id`, `day`, and `event`. I also have a separate list of `user_id`s, and I'm trying to write a query for this Hive table that returns all rows corresponding to the first 48 hours of activity for each user in that list (for each user, there is an initial row in the table with `event = SIGNUP`).

I am a bit stumped as to how to write this query. Does anyone have any pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired rsults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions to calculate the first date for each `user_id`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             min(day) over (partition by user_id) as min_day
      from t
      where t.user_id in ( . . . ) -- your list here
     ) t
where day <= date_add(min_day, 2)
```